# How can I discern which files in my public html folder are used by which domain?

Tags: web, ftp, web-hosting

I inherited two websites on the same host server and several thousand files/directories that are not being used by those websites. I want to remove those files that are not used. I have tried using developer tools on Chrome and looking at the network tab to see what is served to a browser when navigating to those websites but there some files that are never passed to the client. Does anyone know a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: Is the cost of keeping the garbage worth the cost of the investigation (and the potential to accidentally remove too much)?

Comment: yes, the host offers an automatic weekly backup and it is currently triple the size that they will backup for no additional fees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a list of all the files that you have.
Now write a crawler that will crawl over both the websites and each file that is crawled over, remove it from the initial list. 
The list of files that you have now are the ones that are not used by any of those websites.

Comment: Had to look into how to do that to include the database attached, but it worked. Thank you!